# Amazon SageMaker: ClientError: Data download failed:NoSuchKey (404): The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running a SageMaker Training Job with a custom algorithm and the input data from s3. The SagaMaker AIM role ARN has a Read/Put policy on the specified S3 bucket folder, but while creating the job I get a client error:

`ClientError: Data download failed:NoSuchKey (404): The specified key does not exist.`

Unfortunately no more error info is provided in the SageMaker dashboard to investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SageMaker team member here.

The problem here is that the training job in question was setup with S3DataType=ManifestFile. In this case SageMaker expects to be able to download a single manifest file from the location specified by the S3Uri, if the file does not exist in S3 we get a 404 which is what we're sending back as the error here.

See here for documentation on S3DataType/S3Uri and manifests: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_S3DataSource.html#SageMaker-Type-S3DataSource-S3DataType

We will work to make this error message a bit more user-friendly, thanks for calling this out!

Comment: thank you this solved my problem. It turns out that now I have a not sufficient disk space issue.

Comment: great - that should be easy to solve with the VolumeSizeInGB parameter - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_ResourceConfig.html#SageMaker-Type-ResourceConfig-VolumeSizeInGB